# How to use Effector with Class components

Tags: reactjs, store, react-state-management, effector

How can we use effector to connect store with class component instead of using useStore hook from react-effector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
https://effector.dev/docs/api/effector-react/createComponent

See at a real example
https://share.effector.dev/kJoLGB6g